# Consulta que traiga los registros diferentes de otra tabla

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 2 tablas, una es de respuestas de una encuesta y la otra es un registro de personas, ambas tienen como clave primaria su documento de identidad, como puedo hacer para traer las personas que no han realizado la encuesta? es decir que no tengan registros en la tabla de respuestas.

Intente asi:

```
Select a.docidentidad,a.nombres from empleados a 
left join respuestas b on a.docidentidad = b.docidentidad
where a.docidentidad <> b.docidentidad
```

y de esta manera

```
where a.docidentidad != b.docidentidad
```

pero no trae nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas seleccionando el docidentidad y el nombre de los empleados solo desde la tabla EMPLEADOS. 
Uniendo la tabla empleados con respuestas, usando el docidentidad. 
Pero no estás mostrando datos de la tabla respuesta (b).
Para mostrar datos de la tabla respuesta, debes poner una columna de dicha tabla, ejemplo "b.docidentidad" 

Tu problema principal es el WHERE dice 
=> Donde el a.docidentidad no sea igual al b.docidentidad
Lo ideal es que ambos docidentidad, sean iguales
=> WHERE a.docidentidad = b.docidentidad

En resumen, tu SQL deberia ser:

```
Select 
b.docidentidad, 
a.nombres 
from empleados a
left join respuestas b on a.docidentidad = b.docidentidad
where a.docidentidad = b.docidentidad
```

Comment: Pero la pregunta es sobre registros diferentes.

Comment: Si la union de las tablas es con el docidentidad, no le puedes decir al where que traiga los que son diferentes.

imagina el doc identidad a = 1, se une al docidentidad b = 1 (son la misma persona)  y le dices al where, que te los traiga solo cuando ambos sean diferentes, no tiene sentido

Comment: Entonces la pregunta se refiere a que debería mostrar los datos que no están en el join?

Comment: No, si quieres mostrar datos de la tabla b, debes mostralos durante el select. si muestras "b.docidentidad" deberia traerte todos los registros en la tabla respuestas. El join es usado para conectar a ambas tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo has dicho en lenguaje coloquial casi exactamente como se escribiría el SQL. Para obtener el resultado que buscas, utiliza una cláusula not exists en el `where` de la consulta:

```
Select a.docidentidad, a.nombres 
  from empleados a 
 where not exists (select 1
                     from respuestas b
                    where b on b.docidentidad = a.docidentidad)
```

Esto traerá todos aquellos empleados para los que no existe ningún registro en la tabla de respuestas.